Lens not communicating with Panasonic Lumix G9
I have a Panasonic Lumix G Vario 12-60mm f/3.5-5.6 ASPH. POWER O.I.S. Lens, purchased about 15 months ago (so out of warranty) and used on a Panasonic Lumix G9 body. It has seen very light use and today all of a sudden while I was doing some photo/video acquisition I received the following message in the viewfinder:
"Lens attachment failed. Please make sure the lens is attached correctly."
I detached and attached the lens several times, I removed the battery and reinserted it, all to no avail. When I got home I tested other Lumix lenses with the camera and they all worked, so the problem is with the lens. The lens contacts are very clean.
Any idea what could be happening and is there something else to try? If not, what is your experience with Panasonic repair or is there somewhere better to send it?
Thank you.
Edit: I learned that for the cost of repairing the lens, with an indefinitely long expected turnaround time, I could just as well buy a nice used one from a reputable retailer and have it in a couple of days. So I've given up on the repair option.
